# Show all datatips for a single lineseries

Tags: actionscript, flex3

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to show all datatips for a single lineseries in a Flex 3 linechart.  This chart will have multiple lines and the functionality we're looking for is when a user hovers over a line, show all datatips associated with just that series.  Any help would be appreciated.

showAllDataTips will not work in this case as it will display all datatips on the chart.

Thanks!
Rich

Answer (score 1):

Use dataTipItems of the lineseries itself. According to the documentation you can insert all items to this property to make them visislbe.